# Loki rush to beat a 1900 player in Age of Mythology?

Tags: age-of-mythology

I am playing with a friend who is 1900 rated in AOM. When ever we play he always win and I can't seem to beat him. I want to learn a loki rush to beat a 1900 rated player in AOM. can any one give me steps to do a 1900 loki rush?

Answer (score 1):

This is the strat I normally use but it takes time to get used to:

1. Use starting food to train gatherers
2. Ulfsark builds a temple while you put your starting gatherers on to food.
3. Send your Ulf out to scout while you put 3 more gatherers on food (with your starting ones).

   - Use the rest mostly on gold for land or wood for sea.
4. Your Ulf should have found the enemy's base by now. Set up another Temple near the enemy base and start producing Hersir for the rush.

   - You can allocate some of the food you got to gatherers if you want to take precautions.
5. When your Hersir are ready, attack! Focus on enemy villagers and houses, the only exception to this is Norse opponents (Ox carts) while training Raiding Cavalry or more Hesir for a supporting rush.
6. Destroy enemy base

This is a basic rundown of Hesir rush there are multiple variations but I find this more on my style. If you're looking for other Loki rush variations go to this site https://sites.google.com/site/aomloki/lokistrats